# JUnit java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getRequiredTestInstances()

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle, junit5

I was creating some JUnit test cases for my project app (Spring Boot) and encountered the following error stack below when I run my JUnit test cases:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getRequiredTestInstances()Lorg/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstances;
at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.beforeEach(MockitoExtension.java:141)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:130)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:156)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:181)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:218)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:228)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:120)
    ... 43 more
```

[my build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xurHs.jpg)

It was working at first, but when I added the JaCoCo plugin and tried to run it, that's when I encountered the error above. Moreover, I removed it to see if the error will go away. Unfortunately, I still encounter the same error even though I removed the JaCoCo plugin. Can someone help me with my problem? BTW I'm using JUNIT 5.

Comment: Your Jupiter version does not fit your mockito version which requires Jupiter 5.4

Comment: @johanneslink it worked!! I upgraded the jupiter dependency to 5.4.0 THANKS!

Comment: How does one figure out which version of Jupiter is required?

Comment: What about the test class? it only needed `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` and further `@Mock` on objects wanted to be mocked?

Comment: Please include you gradle file as text, not as an image, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 22):

If you are using **junit-jupiter-api** update dependency version to **5.7.0**

Reference [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea)

Comment: ```5.7.0``` never worked for me. I had to use ```5.7.2```. Thanks tho

Answer (score 9):

I got the same problem. I fixed it by replacing all Junit dependencies by this single dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Check [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api) for latest version

Comment: awesome, worked for me as well with v5.8.2

Comment: had `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getConfigurationParameter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/function/Function;)` not found

Answer (score 1):

Worth to check if all junit-jupiter dependencies in the path have the same version.
In my project junit-jupiter dependencies are connected manually and overwrite the vertions from Spring Test. This was the problem in my case.
Run `mvn dependency:tree` and check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SpringBoot, then the Spring dependency management is your problem. SpringBoot maintains some default dependency versions. you need to override those in your pom.xml file's .
Refer [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) to see what versions of junit.jupiter and mockito are used by your springboot version. Then override those in your pom.xml with the intended version. For eg:

```
<properties>
  <junit-jupiter.version>5.7.0</junit-jupiter.version>
  <mockito.version>3.3.3</mockito.version>
</properties>
```

Hopefully, this resolves your issues.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone was I hit the issue mentioned in this post. I get this when I start up my simple @WebMvcTest . All I was trying to get to was to make the @WebMvcTest run and use JUnit5 instead of JUnit 4

This is my basic set up.

- JDK 17
- Spring Boot 3.2 ( and hence I have spring-boot-starter-parent as my  in the pom.xml
- Mockito core 5.7.0 and Mockito-junit-jupiter 5.7.0
- junit-platform-commons  and junit-platform-engine v1.10.1

What I was noticing is that the runtime was trying to load [this] during start up of the test .  Note that this version requires 5.9.x of jupiter api .The junit-jupiter brought in by the spring-boot-starter-test is of v 5.7.x

I have to manually exclude these dependencies ( see pom.xml snippet below) and then individually add the correct versions of the following

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Don't forget to add these four dependencies individually

```
 - junit-jupiter-api v 5.10.1
 - junit-juipter-engine v 5.10.1
 - junit-jupiter-params v 5.10.1
 - junit-jupiter v 5.10.1
```

I had to obviously exclude the older JUnit 4 versions wherever they came up ( could be done my running the mvn dependency:tree on your project to locate and isolate them using the exclusions tag ]).

The only JUnit4 dependencies ( as simple dependency tags )  were as follows

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Important** : ***I was misled by looking at the External Libraries seen on  IntelliJ vs running the  mvn dependency:tree command on terminal . The terminal is the REAL thing , so it would be better to rely on that.***

Also while debugging remove your .m2 folder so that you are not inadvertently caching any stuff that makes it that much more harder to get to the solution.

I am sure there is a better solution  of NOT excluding the libraries provided OOTB by spring-boot-starter-test, but THIS was the only way I could resolve the dependency hell and every mysterious class loading magic.

I hope someone will get a tiny mileage from my several hours of valuable weekend time spent on looking at jupiter versions.