# Spring Boot JUnit 5 test failing with null pointer

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am getting

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getRequiredTestInstances()Lorg/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstances;
at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.beforeEach(MockitoExtension.java:143)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$null$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:126)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)

error for below code.

what the proper way of running below code as junit test?

```
package com.safnas.unittesting.unittesting.business;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import com.safnas.unittesting.unittesting.data.SomeDataService;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SomeBusinessMockTest {
    
    @InjectMocks
    SomeBusinessImpl business = new SomeBusinessImpl();
    
    @Mock
    SomeDataService dataServiceMock;
    
    @Test
    void calculateSumUsingDataService_basic() {
        when(dataServiceMock.retrieveAllData()).thenReturn(new int[] {1,2,3});
        assertEquals(6, business.calculateSumUsingDataService());
    }
    
    @Test
    void calculateSum_empty() {
        when(dataServiceMock.retrieveAllData()).thenReturn(new int[] {});
        assertEquals(0, business.calculateSumUsingDataService());
    }
    
    @Test
    void calculateSum_oneValue() {
        when(dataServiceMock.retrieveAllData()).thenReturn(new int[] {5});
        assertEquals(5, business.calculateSumUsingDataService());
    }

}
```

Comment: try the annotation at class-level: ```@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)```?

Comment: not working still

Comment: then see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60471228/junit-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-junit-jupiter-api-extension-extensioncont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed   @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) and used below

@BeforeEach

```
void beforeEach() {

MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

}
```

it worked fine

as per javadocs

AutoCloseable org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(Object testClass)

Initializes objects annotated with Mockito annotations for given testClass:@org.mockito.Mock, @Spy, @Captor, @InjectMocks

See examples in javadoc for MockitoAnnotations class.
Parameters:testClass Returns:A closable to close when completing any tests in testClass.

Answer (score 0):

one more observation.

without any change, my original question is working in intelliJ

eclipse is only having issue it seems